# How to use an Auto Number field in Access DB in UPDATE statement in c#?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I met this error when I used this as my `OleDbCommand`

```
"UPDATE [Players] SET [Players] = '" + sPlayerName + "' WHERE [ID] = '" + nPlayer + "'"
```

---

```
Error:
Database Error - Unable to Write:
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(Int32 hr)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

this `ID` in the `WHERE` clause is an Auto number field in access database
nPlayer is integer variable

this works when the value is hard coded like this
ex- if value of nPlayer variable is 3 then

```
"....... WHERE [ID] =  3"
```

can some one tell me how to correct this error

Comment: Have you tried leaving out the single quotes? `+ "' WHERE [ID] = " + nPlayer`

Answer (score 3):

It's quite easy

```
Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

This means that you are passing a string and you should pass a number

In this case, you should not use the single quote in the field, so the `WHERE` clause needs to change from this

```
..."WHERE [ID] = '" + nPlayer + "'"
```

to this

```
..."WHERE [ID] = " + nPlayer
```

Answer (score 1):

U should not concat your query, but instead use dbparameters.. Something like this

```
string sql = "UPDATE [Players] SET [Players] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@playerName", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = sPlayerName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@playerId", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 3;

conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Why? 2 Reasons

1) SQL Injection when a player would be able to enter a SQL statement into his name. For a reference see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

2) Performance, the query will be the same and the SQL optimizer does not have to re-analyse the query plan for it. For a reference see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16994/Use-SQL-Parameters-to-Overcome-Ad-Hoc-Performance